# Can I wrap a paragraph of text around image in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

I want to see if it is possible to wrap text around an image in Shiny. I have a shiny dashboard with an 'About' tab with some paragraphs of text and a few images. I've coded a simplified version of the concept below. In a program like MS Word, there are a few different options for how an image can be inline with the text and how the text wraps around an image (See figure at the bottom I created in Word).

My current solution is to use fluidRow() and column() to chop the page up and place the text separately from the image. This could work, but does not provide as clean of a final product as Word's text wrapping features do.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


ui <- dashboardPage(

  # # Dashboard Header
  dashboardHeader(title = "Menu"),
  #

  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Example Tab", tabName = "tabA")
    )
  ), # End Dashboard Sidebar


  # Body of the dashboard
  dashboardBody(

    # Start with overall tabItems
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "tabA",


        fluidRow(
          column(
            width = 10,

            p("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
          incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
          exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
          dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
          Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
          mollit anim id est laborum."),
          ),
          column(
            width = 2,

            img(
              height = 100,

              src = "https://www.r-project.org/logo/Rlogo.png"
            ),
          ), # end column
        ), # end fluidRow

        br(),
        br(),

        fluidRow(
          column(
            width = 8,


            p("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
          incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
          exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
          sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est
          laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
          incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
          nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu
          fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa
          qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.")
          ),

          column(
            width = 4,

            img(
              height = 200,

              src = "https://www.r-project.org/logo/Rlogo.png"
            ),
          ), # end column
        ), # end fluid row
      )
    )
  )
)



####################################################
####################################################

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}




shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: Example in MS Word]

Comment: A [CSS way here](https://codepen.io/demiton/pen/GRgdbYP), and a [JavaScript way here](http://www.jwf.us/projects/jQSlickWrap/). Does it help?

Comment: It seems like there is potential - though I am still a novice and don't know how to make the leap to implement these within Shiny

Comment: Ok wait, I will try to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS way:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

CSS <- "
p {
  line-height: 1.6; 
  font-family: Helvetica;
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.Rlogo {
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
  shape-outside: url(https://www.r-project.org/logo/Rlogo.svg);
  shape-margin: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
"

ui <- dashboardPage(
  
  # # Dashboard Header
  dashboardHeader(title = "Menu"),
  #
  
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Example Tab", tabName = "tabA")
    )
  ), # End Dashboard Sidebar
  
  
  # Body of the dashboard
  dashboardBody(
    
    tags$head(
      tags$style(HTML(CSS))
    ),
    
    # Start with overall tabItems
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "tabA",
        
        fluidRow(
          column(
            width = 12,
            
            img(
              class = "Rlogo",
              src = "https://www.r-project.org/logo/Rlogo.svg"
            ),
            p("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
          incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
          exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
          sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est
          laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
          incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
          nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu
          fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa
          qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.")
            
          ) # end column
          
        ) # end fluid row
      )
    )
  )
)


####################################################
####################################################

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

JavaScript way:

```
CSS <- "
.Rlogo {
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 30px;
}
"

JS <- "
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.Rlogo').slickWrap();
});
" 

ui <- dashboardPage(
  
  # # Dashboard Header
  dashboardHeader(title = "Menu"),
  #
  
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Example Tab", tabName = "tabA")
    )
  ), # End Dashboard Sidebar
  
  
  # Body of the dashboard
  dashboardBody(
    
    tags$head(
      tags$script(src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/jasonwyatt/jQSlickWrap/jquery.slickwrap.js"),
      tags$script(HTML(JS)),
      tags$style(HTML(CSS))
    ),
    
    # Start with overall tabItems
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "tabA",
        
        fluidRow(
          column(
            width = 12,
            
            img(
              class = "Rlogo",
              src = "https://www.r-project.org/logo/Rlogo.svg"
            ),
            p("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
          incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
          exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
          sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est
          laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
          incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
          nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu
          fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa
          qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.")
            
          ) # end column
          
        ) # end fluid row
      )
    )
  )
)


####################################################
####################################################

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this out - I need a bit of extra hand holding right now, and it really helps to have all the components laid out like this.

Answer (score -1):

If you style your `p` with css `text-align` as justified, it should work

```
p(style="text-align: justify;", "Lorem ipsum etc etc")
```

Comment: I tried the following and succeeded in justifying the text portion, but not wrapping text with the image (image was bumped to a new row). Am I missing something in the implementation of the style argument?

```
fluidRow(

p(style="text-align: justify;", "Lorem ipsum etc etc"),
img(src = "website.com")

)
```

Comment: The above answer of @StéphaneLaurent solves this. The trick was to give image css style `float:left`.